# Cookie Authentication in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, security, authentication, reverse-proxy, cookies

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy in Apache. The user will be required to log in, and will then be sent a cookie. I want Apache to check the cookie. Is there a way to do this?

EG, right now my config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:82>
  # username:password sent on to endpoint
  RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic cm9vdjfjDJaGRvYa=="

  ProxyPass /monitors/2/ http://192.168.1.6/foo.cgi
  ProxyPassReverse /monitors/2/ http://192.168.1.6/foo.cgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Can I add something in the VirtualHost to restrict access based on a cookie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. I do the same thing.

When a user logs in, I give them a cookie and create a token in `/t/`*tokenid*, and put it in a cookie: `S=`*tokenid*`;PATH=/`

Then, I can use `RewriteCond` to check for the file's existence:

```
RewriteEngine on
# check for no cookie being set
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !S=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/*protected/ /login.html [L,R]
# check for an invalid cookie being set
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} S=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteCond /t/%1 !-f
RewriteRule ^/*protected/ /login.html [L,R]
```

Finally, a garbage collector runs periodically and deletes old tokens:

```
find /t -type f \! -atime +1 -delete
```

To make the atime automatically update, I have `/t` mounted without `noatime`, and I have it web-accessible (but not indexed) and part of the stylesheet references `/loggedin.txt` which is rewritten as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} S=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/*loggedin\.txt$ /t/%1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is universal, but the Ruby CGI library encodes "=" as "%3D", so my RewriteCond looks like this: RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} S%3D([a-zA-Z0-9]+)